# django-filter not filtering the query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I applied **django-filter** library in my project if it's not filtering the items.
if i visit the url *http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/?q=&category=electronics* it should gives the only electronics products but its giving the all available products. What i am doing wrong? it should filter categories wise or product title wiase and price wise.

```
class ProductFilter(FilterSet):     # by using django-filters
    title = CharFilter(field_name='title', lookup_expr='icontains', distinct=True)
    category = CharFilter(field_name='categories__title', lookup_expr='icontains', distinct=True)
    category_id = CharFilter(field_name='categories__id', lookup_expr='icontains', distinct=True)
    min_price = NumberFilter(field_name='price', lookup_expr='gte', distinct=True)
    max_price = NumberFilter(field_name='price', lookup_expr='lte', distinct=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'description', 'min_price', 'max_price']


class FilterMixin(object):
    filter_class = ProductFilter
    search_ordering_param = 'ordering'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            qs = super(FilterMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            return qs
        except:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You must have a queryset in order to use the FilterMixin")

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(FilterMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        ordering = self.request.GET.get(self.search_ordering_param)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(ordering)
        filter_class = self.filter_class
        print(filter_class)
        if filter_class:
            f = filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
            context['object_list'] = f
        return context


class ProductListView(FilterMixin, ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    filter_class = ProductFilter
    

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['filter_form'] = ProductFilterForm(data=self.request.GET or None)
        return context
```

Template File-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class='col-sm-2'>
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'products:product-list' %}">
{{ filter_form|crispy }}
<input type='hidden' name='q' value='{{ request.GET.q }}' />
<input type='submit' value='Apply Filter' class='btn btn-default'>

</form>

<a href="{% url 'products:product-list' %}">Clear Filters</a>
</div>




<div class='col-sm-12'>
<h3>All Products <small>*<a href="{% url 'categories:category-list'%}">Categories</a>*</small></h3>
{% if product_list %}


     <div class="row">

     {% for product in product_list %}
         <div class="col">
           {% include 'products/snippets/card.html' with instance=product %}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}

      {% else %}
        <p>No product found!!</p>
    {% endif %}

 </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Share the template where you render the items.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem take a look.

Comment: Your `FilterMixin` never exports something like a `product_list`, so that will be the original queryset.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `FilterMixin` contaxt variable `object_list` gives something like this `<products.views.ProductFilter object at 0x05DB4A90>`

Comment: yes, but that has no impact on `product_list`... Furthermore even if that was true, this is *not* how you filter with a filterset, you need to access the `.qs` of the filterset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FilterMixin` never exports something like a `product_list`, so that will be the original queryset, not the one that you filter with the  `FilterSet`.

You can easily update this with:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = context['object_list']
    if self.filter_class:
        qs = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=qs).qs
    ordering = self.request.GET.get(self.search_ordering_param)
    if ordering:
        qs = qs.order_by(ordering)
    context['object_list'] = qs
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(qs)
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = qs
    return context
```

Comment: you didn't define `f ` and queryset it may be `context['object_list'] = qs
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(qs)`

Comment: @RahulVerma: yes, it is simply `qs`.